# Expected value based on probability

Tags: probability, average

Let's suppose I want to determine the weighted average from a set of numbers.

I have x-data and y-data. The x-data corresponds to energies, 1 through 400 eV, in increments of 1 eV. At each energy, I get a certain number of defects produced which is my y-data.

So at 1 eV, I have 0 defects
But at 10 eV, I might have 1 defect
At 20 eV, I might have 1.2 defects (these are already averages) etc.

Is there a way to get a weighted average?

If I take say 400 eV, and see there are 10 defects, then the average energy to create a defect is 40 eV. How can I get a weighted average based on all the energies?

Answer (score 0):

$$P(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{10} P(X|i)P(i)$$
$$=.5*.1+1*.1+1*.1+1*.1$$
(by your given values for $i=7,8,9,10$)
$$=0.35$$

Comment: How could the expected value be 0.35? It needs to be between 1 and 10

Comment: Are you choosing a random number from 1 to 10, then deciding if $X$ will occur based on that number?

Comment: I edited question, sorry I oversimplified it at first